# Is there anything in Quran About Trans Gender?

Tags: homosexuality, transgender

I know that Homosexuality is Haram and it has been stated clearly in many places. But what is the opinion about Trans Genders in Quran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homosexuality is forbidden for the fact that the story of Prophet Lot exists, like adultery, totally out of debate.

On the other hand, the 3rd gender looks more of a myth than what we need to find justification for. One, there's no evidence that a third gender exists.

Two, Allah makes it clear that He only created two genders in mankind, not three:

> ( 53/45 )   *And that He creates the two mates - the male and female -*
>
> ( 53/46 )   *From a sperm-drop when it is emitted*
>
> ( 53/47 )   *And that [incumbent] upon Him is the next creation*

Three, it was decreed that a group [from among mankind] will change in the creation, i.e. the transgenders:

4:119
وَلَأُضِلَّنَّهُمْ وَلَأُمَنِّيَنَّهُمْ وَلَـَٔامُرَنَّهُمْ فَلَيُبَتِّكُنَّ ءَاذَانَ ٱلْأَنْعَـٰمِ وَلَـَٔامُرَنَّهُمْ فَلَيُغَيِّرُنَّ خَلْقَ ٱللَّهِ ۚ وَمَن يَتَّخِذِ ٱلشَّيْطَـٰنَ وَلِيًّا مِّن دُونِ ٱللَّهِ فَقَدْ خَسِرَ خُسْرَانًا مُّبِينًا

> *"And I will mislead them, and I will arouse in them [sinful] desires, and I will command them so they will slit the ears of cattle, **and I will command them so they will change the creation of Allah.**" And whoever takes Satan as an ally instead of Allah has certainly sustained a clear loss.*

Four, a transgender male will never be a man, and a transgender female will never be a woman:

> حَدَّثَنَا مَحْمُودُ بْنُ غَيْلاَنَ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو دَاوُدَ الطَّيَالِسِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، وَهَمَّامٌ، عَنْ قَتَادَةَ، عَنْ عِكْرِمَةَ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، قَالَ لَعَنَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم الْمُتَشَبِّهَاتِ بِالرِّجَالِ مِنَ النِّسَاءِ وَالْمُتَشَبِّهِينَ بِالنِّسَاءِ مِنَ الرِّجَالِ ‏.
>
> "The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) cursed the women who imitate men and the men who imitate women."

Finally, there are special cases that require a surgical interference to define the gender of an individual, that doesn't mean transsexualism is permitted by Allah: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/138451/when-is-it-permissible-to-do-a-sex-change-operation-from-male-to-female-or-vice-versa

Answer (score 2):

Transgender is a big sin and totally haram. A man imitation a woman or woman imitating a man is a MAJOR sin in Islam and transgender also is changing the creation of Allah (swt). Prophet Muhammad (s) also cursed the man who imitates women and cursed the woman who imitates men. Allah (swt) says in the Quran in Surah Nisa verses 118-121, “Allah cursed him. And he (Satan) said: "I will take an appointed portion of your servants." 119. "Verily, I will mislead them, and surely, I will arouse in them false desires; and certainly, I will order them to slit the ears of cattle, and indeed I will order them to change the nature created by Allah.'' And whoever takes Shaytan as a Wali (guardian, protector, helper) instead of Allah, has surely suffered a manifest loss. 120. He (Satan) makes promises to them, and arouses in them false desires; and Satan’s promises are nothing but deceptions. 121. The dwelling of such (people) is Hell, and they will find no way of escape from it.” (Quran Surah Nisa verse 118-121). This is one of the things that Shaytaan (Satan) does it that he will try to get people to change the creation of Allah (swt). A man who goes for surgery to become a woman indeed has not actually become a woman. Can he ever get pregnant and become a mother?! No. A woman who thinks she can become a man also in reality does not actually become a man. We must be content with the creation of Allah (swt) for Allah (swt) is the most perfect and makes no mistakes and there is wisdom behind everything he does. If a person is born a man that’s all he can ever be and if a person is born a woman that’s all she can ever be